# Eliminating extra commas

Tags: python, regex, string, text, text-processing

I am having trouble replacing three commas with one comma in a text file of data.

I am processing a large text file to put it into comma delimited format so I can query it using a database.

I do the following at the command prompt and it works:

```
  >>> import re
  >>> line = 'one,,,two'
  >>> line=re.sub(',+',',',line)
  >>> print line
  one,two
  >>>
```

following below is my actual code:

```
  with open("dmis8.txt", "r") as ifp:
      with open("dmis7.txt", "w") as ofp:
          for line in ifp:
              #join lines by removing a line ending.
              line=re.sub('(?m)(MM/ANGDEC)[\r\n]+$','',line)
              #various replacements of text with nothing. This removes the text
              line=re.sub('IDENTIFIER','',line)
              line=re.sub('PART','50-1437',line)
              line=re.sub('Eval','',line)
              line=re.sub('Feat','',line)
              line=re.sub('=','',line)
              #line=re.sub('r"++++"','',line)
              line=re.sub('r"----|"',' ',line)
              line=re.sub('Nom','',line)
              line=re.sub('Act',' ',line)
              line=re.sub('Dev','',line)
              line=re.sub('LwTol','',line)
              line=re.sub('UpTol','',line)
              line=re.sub(':','',line)
              line=re.sub('(?m)(Trend)[\r\n]*$',' ',line)
              #Remove spaces replace with semicolon
              line=re.sub('[ \v\t\f]+', ',', line)
              #no worky line=re.sub(r",,,",',',line)
              line=re.sub(',+',',',line)
              #line=line.replace(",+", ",")
              #line=line.replace(",,,", ",")
              ofp.write(line)
```

This is what i get from the code above:
There are several commas together. I don't understand why they won't get replaced down to one comma. 
Never mind that I don't see how the extra commas got there in the first place.

```
  50-1437,d
  2012/05/01
  00/08/27
  232_PD_1_DIA,PED_HL1_CR,,,12.482,12.478,-0.004,-0.021,0.020,----|++++
  232_PD_2_DIA_TOP,PED_HL2_TOP,,12.482,12.483,0.001,-0.021,0.020,----|++++
  232_PD_2_DIA,PED_HL2_CR,,12.482,12.477,-0.005,-0.021,0.020,----|++++
  232_PD_2_DIA_BOT,PED_HL2_BOT,,12.482,12.470,-0.012,-0.021,0.020,--|--++++
```

raw data for reference:

```
  PART IDENTIFIER         :  d
  2012/05/01
  00/08/27
  232_PD_1_DIA  Eval Feat =  PED_HL1_CR   MM/ANGDEC
                    Nom           Act           Dev         LwTol         UpTol         Trend
                 12.482        12.478        -0.004        -0.021         0.020     ----|++++

  232_PD_2_DIA_TOP  Eval Feat =  PED_HL2_TOP   MM/ANGDEC
                 12.482        12.483         0.001        -0.021         0.020     ----|++++

  232_PD_2_DIA  Eval Feat =  PED_HL2_CR   MM/ANGDEC
                 12.482        12.477        -0.005        -0.021         0.020     ----|++++
```

Can someone kindly point what I am doing wrong?

thanks in advance...

Comment: I don't see any commas in the raw data. (Aside: if this is Python 2.7 or later you can put both file open calls in the same `with` statement.)

Comment: Looks to me like the commas may come from this line: `line=re.sub('[ \v\t\f]+', ',', line)` (which according to the comment above it should involve semicolons).

Comment: Levon: My goal is to take the raw input and massage it into a comma delimited output file that I can query with SQL in MSAccess or any tool for that matter. I am adding the commas between each field intentionally. There are some good points made by people replying. thank you to all for your efforts in replying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is working fine. The problem is that it you concatenate the lines (by `write()`ing them) *after* you scrub them with your regex.

Instead, use `"".join()` on all of your lines, run `re.sub()` on the whole thing, and then `write()` it all to the file at once.

Comment: thank you for your answser. I think it will help me. I will work on this.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is caused by the fact that **removing line endings does not join lines**, in combination with the fact that `write` does not add newlines to the end each string. So you have multiple input lines that look like a single line in the output.

Looking at the comments, you seem to think that just replacing the end of the line by an empty string will magically append the next line to it, but that doesn't actually work.  So the three commas you're seeing are not replaced by your `re.sub` command because they're *not in one line*, they're multiple input lines (which after all the replacements are empty except for commas) which get printed to a single output line because you stripped their `'\n'` characters, and `write` doesn't automatically add `'\n'` to the end of each written string (unlike `print`).

To debug your code, just put `print line` after each line of code, to see what each "line" actually is - that should help you see what's going wrong.

In general, reading file formats where each "record" spans multiple lines requires more complicated methods than just a `for line in file` loop.

Comment: thank you for your answser. I think it will help me. I will work on this.

Comment: thank you all. I took the lazy way out and just ran through the file again after this to eliminate the extra commas. I think i understand better what was wrong. this is closed.

Comment: @david1212 - if you're done with this question, you may want to accept one of the answers (click on the white checkmark).